# When to use which "akshari" mantra and the mool mantra?

Tags: mantras

Almost every God has a `mool mantra`, then there are `treyakshari`, `panchakshari`, `ashtakshari`  etc. mantras.
Is there a guideline on which mantra to choose for what purpose?
Couldnt find any literature talking about this, so hoping someone here could help.